# How to properly use sklearn cosine_similarity with a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a csv file that contains an id, and then 4000 extra columns of floating point numbers.
so a row looks like:

```
12323,3.8,3.1,4.2,.....
```

I am trying to compare a single row with the others rows to fid which rows re most similar  using a cosine distance metric. Currently, I compare each row from a numpy array individually to a single item. I want to be able to compare all the items at once instead of comparing one item at a time.  The problem is I use a dictionary because I use the key to reference each object. As you can see in the code below, dict stores the id as as the key and then the value is the an array of the floating point numbers.

```
#item is the single item
dict= {}
scores = {}
with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
  for row in reader:
    dict[row[1]] = np.loadtxt(row[2:],delimiter=',')

for k,v in dict.iteritems():
  score = cosine_similarity(item,v)
  scores[k] = score
sorted_scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(sorted_scores[-args.k:])
```

how can I  get the same result but without using the for loop to individually score each row. From reading the distance metrics I should be able to pass a whole array of rows into cosine_similarity.

Comment: in case you missed it, I updated my code and explained how it works according to your comment. You can actually do as you say ` dist = pairwise.pairwise_distances(X[:,1:], main_object,metric='cosine')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances` which returns you a distance matrix, so you don't have to loop.

You can build a `dictionary` of `id` correspondences so you can compute distances and then easily access to them.

Working example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import  pairwise 

main_object = [0.8,0.8]

X = np.matrix([
    [12345,0.8,0.9],
    [11111,0.9,0.1],
    [22222,0.7,.8]])

# you create a dictionary of <key=id, value=position(row in samples)>
dict_ids = {idx:int(id.item(0,0)) for idx,id in enumerate(X[:,0:1])}
print dict_ids 

# calculating distances in one shot, X[:,1:] this syntax omits ids col
dist = pairwise.pairwise_distances(X[:,1:], main_object, metric='cosine')
print dist 

# in dist now you have all distances to 'main_object'. Now you can play with it, for example if you want min dist:
print 'id:',dict_ids[np.argmin(dist)], 'dist:',min(dist)
# output id: 12345 dist: [ 0.00172563]
```

Comment: I dont think this will work. I have 1 main object stored in a variable called main_object.  Then in your array X, I want to compare it to all of them so I can find the objects that are most similar to that main object.  With the code you wrote, I dont see how I could use this.  So the comparison is something like:     dist = pairwise.pairwise_distances(X[:,1:], main_object,metric='cosine')

Comment: yeah, sure you can :) Sorry, I didn't get your question right at first. Just updated my code example. But yeah, definitely you can pass a sample to compare the rest with, signature `pairwise_distances(X, Y=None,... `. So, as the documentation states "If Y is given (default is None), then the returned matrix is the pairwise distance between the arrays from both X and Y." I think that fits to your requirements.

Comment: Why are you using the min distance as opposed to the max distance here?

Comment: Because the person who asked the question wanted to retrieve the "most similar". If you use `cosine_similarity` and you want to retrieve the most similar, you'd certainly use `max` as `1.` would mean exactly the same.

Here I'm using `pairwise_distances`, so the closest is the instance with minimal distance https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html